# inotifywait not detecting links

Tags: symbolic-link, inotify

I have successfully created a watcher for modifications inside a directory, recursively:

```
inotifywait -m -r -e modify --format '%w%f' "$Path" | while read File
do
    echo "File $File is modified"
done
```

However, I have some symbolic links inside that directory. And when I open them in an editor and change them, `inotifywait` does not print anything.

I think it's because the actual files are in another directory.

How can I tell `inotifywait` to detect changes of links too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `inotifywait` watches the symbolic links themselves, not the files they point to.

Behind the scenes `inotifywait` uses the `inotify` syscall with the `IN_DONT_FOLLOW` flag, which causes this behaviour. If you want to change that you would need to write your own `inotifywait`, without the flag.

I got this from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769503/use-inotify-to-watch-a-file-with-multiple-symlinks).

Comment: Thanks @Jos, now I know that I need to spend two more weeks to find out another solution. That's the life we have chosen as people of modern technologies.

Comment: Another solution would be to...run `inotifywait` on the linked directories themselves, maybe? There, I saved you two weeks. ;-)

Comment: :)), thank you. However, if I watch **linked file** instead of **linking file**, then I have to find out the **linking file**.

Comment: This is not true if you're using `inotifywait` v3.14. It follows symlinks recursively because it doesn't use the `IN_DONT_FOLLOW` option. Newer versions offer a `-P`/`--no-dereference` option (which is not available on v3.14).